# not able to change environment variable value from shell script

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables, zsh

I have exported a environment variable in my `.zshrc` and I want to update it from a script in `/bin/script.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $TOGGLE -eq 1 ]; then
echo a;
else 
echo b;
fi

TOGGLE=$((TOGGLE * -1));
```

but after the run the script the value of `TOGGLE` is unchanged in the session where I run the script on.
how can I force it to change

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/060 but `zsh` is not `bash` jfyi.

Comment: @RootOfMinusOne : You forgot to say **how** you run the script. If you execute it as `source .../script.sh` (but I hope you don't really have it stored in `/bin`, as your question implies), you should see the variable _TOGGLE_. Aside from this, it is **not** an environment variable, and you did **not** export something in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a FAQ. Environment variables are private to each process, not global. Your script runs as a separate process and therefore cannot directly manipulate the env vars of its parent process. You could `source` the script which would cause it to be executed in the current shell process rather than a subshell. That, however, can have unwanted side effects to the state of the current shell.

Comment: I created a function in my ```. zshrc``` and put the script in it.